# Does Android WebKit support postMessage() for inter-frame communication?

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webkit, postmessage

I am using `postMessage` and `addEventListener("message", ... , false)` for inter-frame communication in our javascript application.

Messages work and are successfully transmitted between frames when I test on Mobile Safari (iOS / iPad), Playbook's WebKit, and desktop Chrome, but on a Galaxy Tab 10.1, the call to postMessage() silently fails. No exceptions are thrown, no errors show up, and the line immediately after postMessage never runs.

Is postMessage() fully supported on Android's WebKit? Is there a different syntax or something I have to do to get it working?

Comment: Are you just using the default browser?

Comment: this is also my issue

Comment: Yes it does work... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164205/can-the-postmessage-api-be-used-to-communicate-with-an-android-webview/39879882#39879882